# Angularfire2 remove all items with matching UserId

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am using angularfire2 in an Ionic App. I am trying to remove from a firebase node all entries that match a user ID. I have a loyalty points node and when I run my reset function I want to remove all entries from the loyaltypoints node related to that user.

[image: Image of firebase list showing all entries with matching userId]

I have managed to get all the entries into a variable called 'myPoints' by adding this into my constructor:

```js
this.angularfire.auth.subscribe(res => {
   if (res != null) {
     let userID = res.auth.uid;
     this.af.list('/loyaltypoints', {
        query: {
           orderByChild: 'userId',
           equalTo: userID,
        }
     }).subscribe(response => {
        this.myPoints = response;
     })
   }
})
```

I dont know how to run a remove() function on the this.myPoints variable to remove all these entries now.

thank you

---

UPDATE

So this seems to work for me, first of all import take like so:
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

Then this code deletes all the related firebase entries:

```
this.angularfire.auth.subscribe(res => {
        if (res != null) {
            let userID = res.auth.uid;
            this.af.list('/loyaltypoints', {
                preserveSnapshot: true,
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'userId',
                    equalTo: userID,
                }
            }).take(1).subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response)
                response.forEach((snapshot) => {
                    this.af.object('/loyaltypoints/' + snapshot.key).remove();
                })

            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you are missing is getting the keys that correspond to each loyaltypoints entry.

```
this.angularfire.auth.subscribe(res => {
if (res != null) {
 let userID = res.auth.uid;
 this.af.list('/loyaltypoints', {
    preserveSnapshot: true,
    query: {
       orderByChild: 'userId',
       equalTo: userID,
    }
 }).take(1).subscribe(snaphots=> {
    snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
        this.af.object('/loyaltypoints/' + snapshot.key).remove();
    }) 

 })
}
})
```

If you notice I added a take(1) because I if you're changing the node your subscribing too, it triggers a fetch of the data again.  You might have to play with this a little to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Ok tried this, I have it all without any errors, however, when I run ionic serve -lab, I am getting forEach is undefined. I did a console.log(this.snapshots) and it returned undefined. so when it takes 1 and subscribes it is not getting anything?

Comment: So for some reason I changed the variable 'snapshots' to 'response' and would you believe it, it worked!! How very strange? Thank you so much for your amazing guidance @getbuckts, I couldn't have done it without you!